# Save Attachments Server with IMAP and PHP

Tags: php, imap

Right now I am using this code to fetch emails from my server.

```
<?php
$imap = imap_open($server, $username, $password) or die("Connection Error");
$message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $message_count; ++$i){

    $header = imap_header($imap, $i);
    //print_r($header);

    $email[$i]['fromaddress'] = $header->from[0]->personal;
    $email[$i]['to'] = $header->to[0]->mailbox;
    $email[$i]['subject'] = $header->subject;
    $email[$i]['message_id'] = $header->message_id;
    $email[$i]['date'] = $header->udate;

    $from = $email[$i]['fromaddress'];
    $from_email = $email[$i]['from'];
    $to = $email[$i]['to'];
    $subject = $email[$i]['subject'];

    echo $from_email . '</br>';
    echo $to . '</br>';
    echo $subject . '</br>';

    imap_setflag_full($imap, $i, "\\Seen");
    imap_mail_move($imap, $i, 'Trash');
}

imap_close($imap);

?>
```

I would like to be able to take the attachments as well and save them to a folder on my server and display a link to those attachments in the output.  What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+imap+attachments) first? There are lots of examples out there. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773169/extracting-php-imap-attachments

Comment: Yes I have used Google and have seen that Stack post.  Unfortunately I could not get that working in my script.

Comment: So, what errors did you encounter? Can you paste the script that you wrote, following those examples?

Comment: I was actually able to get it working this morning.  I was wondering though.  How reliable is it to use the message numbers?  For example... If the script is in the middle of processing and another email comes in, will it throw the message numbers off or is it smart enough to know the difference?

Answer (score 24):

I actually was able to get it to do exactly what I wanted with the following:

```
<?php

function getFileExtension($fileName){
   $parts=explode(".",$fileName);
   return $parts[count($parts)-1];
}

$imap = imap_open($server, $username, $password) or die("imap connection error");
$message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);
for ($m = 1; $m <= $message_count; ++$m){

    $header = imap_header($imap, $m);
    //print_r($header);

    $email[$m]['from'] = $header->from[0]->mailbox.'@'.$header->from[0]->host;
    $email[$m]['fromaddress'] = $header->from[0]->personal;
    $email[$m]['to'] = $header->to[0]->mailbox;
    $email[$m]['subject'] = $header->subject;
    $email[$m]['message_id'] = $header->message_id;
    $email[$m]['date'] = $header->udate;

    $from = $email[$m]['fromaddress'];
    $from_email = $email[$m]['from'];
    $to = $email[$m]['to'];
    $subject = $email[$m]['subject'];

    echo $from_email . '</br>';
    echo $to . '</br>';
    echo $subject . '</br>';

    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $m);

    $attachments = array();
    if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

        for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

            $attachments[$i] = array(
                'is_attachment' => false,
                'filename' => '',
                'name' => '',
                'attachment' => ''
            );

            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($imap, $m, $i+1);
                if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
                elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
        $name = $attachment['name'];
        $contents = $attachment['attachment'];
        file_put_contents($name, $contents);
    }

    //imap_setflag_full($imap, $i, "\\Seen");
    //imap_mail_move($imap, $i, 'Trash');
}

imap_close($imap);

?>
```

Comment: Just tried this. Worked first time. Big thumbs up! Now I just need to figure out how to get the attachment to save on the server.

Comment: Damon, where you able to do this?

Comment: The code to save the file on server is already there, have a look on the last foreach loop in the code: file_put_contents($name, $contents);

Comment: $contents prints out strings like: PK Ȫ�:file to download.txt/UX��SU�sJJPPK Ȫ�:file to download.txt/LgDoc/UX��SU�sJJPPKԪ�:)file to download.txt/LgDoc/displayStateUX��SUtJJP�Zxו>3��1��mI#[�ɶ0��l���`�8�YcŲ�J2؅4�$_�n�4��SJHh�/�6!m�ɫ$ېy�l�l!iIH6�=���2_BZl���73g�s���c��u9���8@��…. How can I get the link from this?

Comment: for  me it is saving 0kb files, i debuged `$attachment['attachment']` is null

Comment: Can you kindly check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745784/how-to-fetch-to-and-cc-email-using-imap-php) need help

Comment: *"Good Job. Just 1 thing, it the commented out area, `$i` should be changed to `$m`."* - [Milad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7637900/milad) (not enough rep. to post a comment.)

Comment: How do you get back the attachment from BASE64 encoding ?

Comment: @alamnaryab to prevent 0byte file, add the `file_put_contents($name, $contents);` outside of the foreach loop.

Comment: @Jeff Thomas you helped me with my final exam project so thanks alot !!!