# Move IMAP messages to my webserver upload directory

Tags: php, email, imap, email-attachments

I have a resume email parser in my application. User will just send resume through email and my system will parse it.

I have a question, is it possible that the resume being sent through email which is now an imap messages can be save into my web server upload directory? I want to save it into public_html/uploads. Is there anyway to do it so?

Any idea?

Comment: is resume attached to the mail as attachment or is a text mail???  and you want to save this extracted resume to some folder named public_html/uploads right??? do you have access to imap code and the storage where mails are kept???

Comment: It is an attached document and I want to save the attached document also in my uploads directory. For the user to be able to view the file that they sent.

Comment: Yes, I have access to my imap code and storage where the mails are kept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefits of others, I have finally make it work. I used file_put_contents(). This post help me figure out, [Save Attachments Server with IMAP and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467188/save-attachments-server-with-imap-and-php)