# Scrape excel or csv from certain ROW and Column and export to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, scrape

So I have used Nokorigi/Mechanize (RUBY) to scrape webpages with logins.

But now I need something that will receive an email with a csv file independently of the file name and it should not duplicate, open it , scrape starting from maybe row 3 which is the one with headers and export it all to mysql.I went and read PHP EXCEL but its not so complete

I was reading PHP EXCEL but I need something like a good scraper.

Any suggestions?

Comment: PHPExcel is not a web scraper or an email scraper, it's a reader/writer for Excel files... if you want it to parse content from an email, then you need to extract the content from that email into a recognised file format

Comment: Right, so do you know what should I use? the reason I want to scrape is because it has to be from another row.

Comment: I doubt if there is any single library that will do what you want, because it's such a specialised function.... you may need to combine several different libraries, and do some work to integrate them to achieve what you want

Comment: I found the email function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467188/save-attachments-server-with-imap-and-php
and this https://classic.scraperwiki.com/scrapers/new/ruby?template=advanced-scraping-excel-files-1 for excel scraping